# Estoy intentando recibir un Json con varios registros ingresados ,

Tags: json, lista, spring

```
@PostMapping("/crearPersonas")
public ResponseEntity <?> crearPersonas(@RequestBody CrearPersonaDto personaDto){
    
    ResponseDto response = new ResponseDto();
    response.setCodigo(Codigo.OK);
    response.setDescripcion("Personas insertadas correctamente");
    
    try {
        response.setData(personaService.insertarPersonas(personaDto).getData());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.setCodigo(Codigo.NO_OK);
        response.setDescripcion(e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: quiero agregar esa lista el tema que no se como hacerlo

Comment: Si Tal cual eso eso lo que tengo que hacer igual tengo algunas ideas , no pude escribir bien la pregunta porque me si no me pasaba en la cantidad de caracteres

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende tu pregunta, más sin embargo deduzco que lo que quieres hacer es recibir una lista de objeto CrearPersonaDto y así crear las personas que recibas.

He aquí el código si es correcto lo que he dicho.

```
@PostMapping("/crearPersonas")
public ResponseEntity <?> crearPersonas(@RequestBody List<CrearPersonaDto> personas){
    
    ResponseDto response = new ResponseDto();
    try {
        for(CrearPersonaDto personaDto:personas){
           response.setData(personaService.insertarPersonas(personaDto).getData());
        }
        response.setCodigo(Codigo.OK);
        response.setDescripcion("Personas insertadas correctamente");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.setCodigo(Codigo.NO_OK);
        response.setDescripcion(e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Esto considerando que CrearPersonaDto es un Objeto que contiene atributos de la persona.